# Cmake doesn't set assembler flag to armasm (for WinCE)

Tags: c++, assembly, boost, cmake, windows-ce

I'm trying to compile the following assembler files to build Boost Context libraries for WinCE:
jump_arm_aapcs_pe_armasm.S
make_arm_aapcs_pe_armasm.S

The Cmake doesn't compile these assembly files for windows CE, as the there is no support for winCE ARM assembler. We tried setting the assembler flag "set(CMAKE_ASM_MASM_COMPILER armasm)" in the cmake config file, still cmake doesn't recognize the assembly code.

Someone please let me know what is the correct way to set the assembler flags in cmake. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a compiler for your asm:
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER "path to your compiler")

For example: 
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER "/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-as")

But first of all try to simple build your asm file with your compiler(without CMake or any another wrapper).